# Bookkeeping in the Roman Empire

Tags: vocabulary

There were no books in the modern sense: there were scrolls. Roman economy was a pretty complicated thing, though, which means some form of bookkeeping had to exist.

If you were to write a novel or a play about the Roman Empire, what would you call a bookkeeper? Someone who's good at math and will, for a fee, shuffle parchment or papyrus for an Emperor who's just hired an architect and a bunch of engineers and contractors to build an aqueduct?

Comment: Didn't "bookkeeping" belong among the duties of the scribe? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scriba_(ancient_Rome)

Comment: I don't know. Did it?

Comment: Maybe this will help...http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjABahUKEwiI-qfM8-7IAhVI_g4KHTj6COM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uwyo.edu%2Flawlib%2Fblume-justinian%2Fajc-edition-2%2Fbooks%2Fbook10%2Fbook10-71rev.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFj43oS-opVSU3m2BilDVaF-nNRgQ

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Roman official involved in the "general and financial administration" of the state was called a *tabularius* (plural, *tabluarii*).  They must have been sharp, since they had to do their work without a zero.  They eventually became trusted to take on private duties like drawing up wills.  It seems that the *[Encyclopedic Dictionary of Roman Law](https://books.google.com/books?id=iklePELtR6QC&pg=PA729&lpg=PA729&dq=tabularius%20roman&source=bl&ots=OiWZEDzN0q&sig=aoQ8dTS3u2sqBIMGWB9Z5VwkTiA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwATgKahUKEwjkrPyh7u7IAhXE8CYKHeuOAGM#v=onepage&q=tabularius%20roman&f=false)* by Adolf Berger might be a considerable help in your effort, particularly in avoiding anachronisms in your nomenclature.

There's a description [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=nlTq36p-XmEC&pg=PP468&lpg=PP468&dq=tabularius%20roman&source=bl&ots=_Xm2x-RqUH&sig=Ji8tluEaK4OdoglsYVNQ5Ryt_OA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCwQ6AEwBGoVChMI29W68u3uyAIVwvM-Ch2gagc-#v=onepage&q=tabularius%20roman&f=false) of the *tabularis a marmoribus* or marble yard administrator.  Perhaps there were tabularii keeping track of the stone supplies for aqueduct projects.